# Get every childs of every childs of an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, children

Let's say I have an element, `document.createElement("div")`, we'll call it `myDiv` `myDiv.innerHTML = "<div><p></p></div>"`, now `myDiv` has a child: a `div`. And this `div` has a child, a `p`. I know I can get `myDiv`'s childs using `myDiv.childNodes`, and the `div`'s using `myDiv.childNodes[0].childNodes`. But now  how can I get every childs of every childs, like every childs that exist? Example:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "<div><p></p><i></i></div></p></p>"
myDiv.someMethod((childs) => {
   // childs should return the `div`, the `div`'s childs (`p` & `i`) and `p` 
})
```

Comment: You don't need to know which ones are children and which are grandchildren, much less whose grandchildren they are?  In what form do want all of these nodes returned?

Comment: All in an array, even if some are children and some other and grandchildren.

Comment: How about using querySelectorAll?

const childArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(myDiv.querySelectorAll('*'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Element.querySelectorAll`

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `<div><p></p><i></i></div><p></p>`;

console.log([...div.querySelectorAll('*')])
```